# Is it possible to install a private key with an Android app?

Tags: android, security

Is it possible to deliver a private key with an Android app, which is the same for all app installations, and which cannot be extracted from the .apk file?

The reason I need this is the following:

1. When my app sends data to the server, (let's say an app key, which may be public), it also sends the hash of this app key, signed with the private key installed during the installation process.
2. The server checks the signature by applying the public key to the signed, hashed app key and comparing the result to the hashed app key.
3. Only if the signature is correct, will sensitive data like an app secret for the access of my API be returned.

This way I like to make sure that only my app can use my API and the app secret cannot be stolen (app key and app secret are necessary to retrieve an access token from the API).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Instance ID seems to be what I am looking for (runs on Android and iOS). This library enables you to assign unique IDs to each installed app instance and to perform a check on the server side, whether the ID belongs to your app.

More information can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/).